How to Qualify for Apple Privacy Manifest with React Native 0.70.15?
I'm currently developing a mobile app using React Native version 0.70.15, and I've recently learned about Apple's requirement for apps to include an Apple Privacy Manifest when submitting to the App Store. However, since React Native 0.70.15 has reached its end of support and newer versions are not available, I'm unsure how to proceed.
Could someone provide suggestions on how I can make my React Native app qualify for the Apple Privacy Manifest? Additionally, how can I determine if my app requires this manifest, and what information should be included in it? Since I'm unable to upgrade to newer React Native versions at the moment, any advice on addressing this issue with my current setup would be greatly appreciated.
Support for How to acheive Integrating this privacy Manifest into React Native App 0.70.15
